# How to provide files to the pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a `docker-compose.yaml` file, that has the following content:

```
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:11.0.2
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      TZ: UTC
      KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME: theme-minimal
      KEYCLOAK_WELCOME_THEME: theme-minimal
      #KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
    ports:
      - 8088:8080
    command:
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"
#      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/export-dir -Dkeycloak.migration.usersPerFile=1000 -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"
    volumes:
      - ./_resources/demo-config/standalone-ha.xml:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
      - ./_resources/demo-config/import-dir:/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir
      - ./_resources/demo-config/export-dir:/opt/jboss/keycloak/export-dir
      #- ./theme-minimal/src/main/resources/theme/theme-minimal:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/theme-minimal
      - ./theme-minimal/target/theme-minimal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/theme-minimal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      - ./provider-domain/target/provider-domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/provider-domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      - ./spi-registration-profile/target/spi-registration-profile-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/spi-registration-profile-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      - ./spi-resource/target/spi-resource-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/spi-resource-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      - ./spi-event-listener/target/spi-event-listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/spi-event-listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      - ./spi-mail-template-override/target/spi-mail-template-override-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/spi-mail-template-override-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now I would like deploy Keycloak on Kubernetes and do not know, how to bind and provide volumes with content in Kubernetes like I do it above in Docker.
I read the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-volume-storage/), how to create storage in Kubernetes but it does not say, how to provide a storage with content.

My Kubernetes cluster is managed by Digital Ocean.

Comment: You need to build a custom image with those jar files, a ConfigMap with the XML configuration, and use a volume of some sort for the certificates it generates.  Have you gotten a simpler application deployed, or looked for a prebuilt deployment?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your files are on your node you can use [`hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).  You will need following fields in your pod manifest:

```yaml
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /<directory_with_files>
      name: volume
  volumes:
  - name: volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

`mountPath` is path within the container at which the volume should be mounted.

`path` under`hostPath` field is path of the directory on the host. If the path is a symlink, it will follow the link to the real path.

Other option for digital ocean might be to use [`Block Storage Volumes`](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/volumes/). You can follow official documentation on [how to add volumes](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/add-volumes/). First of all you will need to define a `PersistentVolumeClaim` object:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: csi-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
```

After PVC is created you can define it in your pod manifest, for example:

```yaml
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/data" #defines where it should be mounted
        name: my-do-volume
  volumes:
    - name: my-do-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: csi-pvc
```